# How to send an email message for a person with out saving it in the sent item for a specific recepient

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How to send an email message for a person with out saving it in the sent item for a specific recepient?
Can I create a rule for that recepient that after sending the mail it should not get saved in the sent items?

Comment: You could set up a rule to delete any emails in the sent folder sent to that person. Unless you specifically don't want a record of it?

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

As *admintech* said, you can add a rule that all mails sent to a specific person/e-mail address to be deleted after send.

You can customize an existing rule template:

[image]

Click on the **people or public group** to add the email address, then click on the **specified** and select **Deleted Items**

[image]

**UPDATE** - manually run rules.

Click on the **Rules** button and select **Manage Rules & Alerts**

[image]

Click on the **Run Rules Now ...** button and select the rule you want to run. Make sure you are in the correct folder (click **Browse** and select *Sent Items*)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for help.Its not working.It should not move the message to sent items.But Its still moving the message to sent items.I give you an example.If i send message to abc@dent.com then the message shouldnt go to sent items folder.                                                             So Please help.

Comment: Correct, you'll have to run the rule manually in Sent Items folder ...

Comment: How to do that?I tried to do it using above mentioned way,Its not working.

Comment: I added more details, see updated answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for help.I have tried the above steps.It is working fine.But I have to manually run the rule on sent items folder then it is moving to the specified folder.Can it happen like with out running manually the message will be moved to specified folder?